# Does the system() function belong to C or C++?

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main ()
{
   system("dir");
}
```

I have read in many C++ books where `system()` is used to execute command line programs. But when I tried the same command in C, it worked perfectly. So my question is whether its a standard C or C++ function? Please be liberal as I am new to C programming.

Comment: It's both.  But `void main` isn't legal in either.

Comment: @JamesKanze actually, many compilers for embedded systems (of course, implementing non-standard extensions) do expect `void main()`.

Comment: @FilippoLauria Perhaps, but unless specified in the question, it should be assumed a general question about Standard C++

Comment: @FilippoLauria But do they also support `system`?  A non-hosted environment has a lot of freedom; how it starts up is implementation defined, and most of the standard library (including `system`) is optional.  In most cases, I would not expect a non-hosted environment to support `system` (and certainly not `system( "dir" )`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both c and cpp support the function system as they have support for the stdlib.h that contains the prototype of system() function.

Answer (score 5):

As system function is declared in stdlib.h, it can be considered a C function. But in C++, stdlib.h is merged into the std namespace and is located in the cstdlib include in this form. So the correct answer is "both".

Answer (score 4):

It is both C and C++.

- system : http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/system
- std::system: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system

Answer (score 4):

Both: it's defined by the standard C library, and the standard C++ library contains the C library.

In C++, you should include the C++ style header, `<cstdlib>`, and refer to it as `std::system`. Including C headers directly is deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

It's both. C defines many functions. C++ defines many functions that are exactly the same as in C, some that are subtly different from how they are in C, and a lot of functions and classes that aren't part of C at all. Knowing that a function is part of standard C++ says nothing about whether it is part of standard C, and knowing that a function is part of standard C says little about whether it is part of standard C++.